# Problem finding return address for shellcode

Tags: gdb, buffer-overflow

Howdy guys and ghouls,

I've got a classic b0f, in fact it's the protostar stack5 exercise

[link to stack5 code](https://exploit-exercises.com/protostar/stack5/)

Now I have the buffer + shellcode running up to overwriting EIP and I need to provide the address to overflow EIP. What's the right way of deducing the return address? I've tried ESP - len(shellcode) but this doesn't seem to work.

How do you go about calculating the right return address (the more precise the better)?

GDB related examples appreciated.

Comment: This question might be better asked at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: overflow EIP? you're sure you're not mixing register names?

Answer (score 6):

Nothing easier than that. `gdb` the executable, set a breakpoint at `main`, have gdb print your buffer.

```
$ gdb /opt/protostar/bin/stack5
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483cd: file stack5/stack5.c, line 10.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/stack5 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0xffffd674) at stack5/stack5.c:10
10  stack5/stack5.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) print &buffer
$1 = (char (*)[64]) 0xbffff838
(gdb)
```

So, if your shellcode starts at byte 0 of the buffer, you want to overwrite the saved EIP on the stack with `0xbffff838`.

In fact, to make your exploit independent from small changes in the program (one more local variable, or one less ...) i'd fill the buffer with 32 `nop`s (`0x90`) and put my shellcode behind those `nop`s. This still leaves you with 32 bytes for the shellcode, which should be plenty. Then, jump to `0xbffff848` which is 16 bytes into the nops, and shifting them around by a few bytes won't hurt you anymore.

At the end, instead of calculating how many bytes between the end of the buffer and the saved `EIP`, i'd just repeat the buffer address a few times, so you can be sure EIP gets overwritten; you don't really care about whatever else is there.

So to sum it up, your input should be

```
0x90 (32 times)
your shellcode
as many 0x90's as you need to fill the buffer to 64 bytes
0x48 0xf8 0xff 0xbf  repeated about 10 times.
```

Remember to swap the `EIP` bytes because we're on a little endian machine.

Comment: `(gdb) print &buffer` returns
`No symbol "buffer" in current context.`

Comment: @Guntram Blohm How to make sure that each time you run program, you have the same return address? Does it change with each execution of program?